# How to set SelectListItem in SelectList/@Html.DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I set the value of a SelectList/@Html.DropDownList given the following code?

--Controller:

```
     public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Order o = db.Orders.Find(id);

        ViewBag.OrderStatusTId = new SelectList(db.OrderStatusTIds, "OrderStatusTId", "Name", o.OrderStatusTId);  // I thought the last item would send in the selected item to the view?!?!?
        return View(o);
     }
```

--View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("OrderStatusTId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OrderStatusTId, String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use viewdata instead of viewbag and change your helper to:

@Html.DropDownList("OrderStatusTId",null, String.Empty)

Comment: Thx! Q1: So why ViewData instead of ViewBag?  Q2: How could I set the selected list item from the list itself (Dropdownlist) within the View instead of passing it in from the controller?

Comment: DropDownList method automatically looks for a list with the name of the dropdown in the viewdata if you pass null on the items. Yes you could but that would not be recommened since all your logic should remain on your controller.